# Siamese networks for comparison of a dataset with multiple features (text, numeric, and ordinal)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, correlation, siamese

Lets assume I have a dataset where each row has ordinal, numerical, and free text columns/features.

Some of the rows are grouped together i.e.:

```
group1 = [row1, row10, row125,.. ] 
group2 = [row2, row8, row64,...  ] 
group3 = [row4, row66, row225,...]
...
```

then, the rest of the dataset is ungrouped but may belong in one of the groups. A row can only belong in one group - but some features - might be the same in more than one group such as text for example.

I thought about creating a Siamese Network with triplet loss - where I create the training set by permutating each row index in a group - then adding a negative example from the other groups. One sample would look like this:

```
(a row from Group 1, another row from Group 1, a row from Group other than 1)
```

Is the Siamese Network appropriate for the scenario? And, is it okay to input different input types at it - since typically we only see text or only images?

Comment: "No two rows can belong in more than one group." Wouldn't that mean that there is only a single group?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is your final goal? Clustering?

Comment: @frank Sorry, I said that wrong - I meant a row can only be in one group.  I want to potentially find out where do the ungrouped rows belong - to which group are they closer.